# Facebook Photo Downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to download Facebook albums of photos from a user in my app. Unfortunately although I do have an access token, I am getting zero albums from the requests. I am not getting an error, just getting zero. Why? If you would like to see any more code or ask more questions, just ask. Note that I have authorized the current user's Facebook permissions when they signed up, and I've since quit the app and opened it many times (don't think this would be an issue, since I have an access token..?)

```
- (void)getAlbums:(OLFacebookAlbumRequestHandler)handler {
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    // connection is open, perform the request
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSString *graphPath = @"me/albums?limit=100&fields=id,name,count,cover_photo";
    if (self.after) {
        graphPath = [graphPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"&after=%@", self.after];
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        if (self.cancelled) {
            return;
        }
        if (error) {
            [OLFacebookAlbumRequest handleFacebookError:error completionHandler:handler];
            return;
        }

        NSString *parsingErrorMessage = @"Failed to parse Facebook Response. Please check your internet connectivity and try again.";
        NSError *parsingError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kOLErrorDomainFacebookImagePicker code:kOLErrorCodeFacebookImagePickerBadResponse userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: parsingErrorMessage}];
        id data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        if (![data isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            handler(nil, parsingError, nil);
            return;
        }

        NSMutableArray *albums = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (id album in data) {
            if (![album isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                continue;
            }

            id albumId     = [album objectForKey:@"id"];
            id photoCount  = [album objectForKey:@"count"];
            id name        = [album objectForKey:@"name"];

            if (!([albumId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [photoCount isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]
                   && [name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
                continue;
            }

            OLFacebookAlbum *album = [[OLFacebookAlbum alloc] init];
            album.albumId = albumId;
            album.photoCount = [photoCount unsignedIntegerValue];
            album.name = name;
            album.coverPhotoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=small&access_token=%@", album.albumId, [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString]];
            [albums addObject:album];
        }

        // get next page cursor
        OLFacebookAlbumRequest *nextPageRequest = nil;
        id paging = [result objectForKey:@"paging"];
        if ([paging isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            id cursors = [paging objectForKey:@"cursors"];
            id next = [paging objectForKey:@"next"]; // next will be non nil if a next page exists
            if (next && [cursors isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                id after = [cursors objectForKey:@"after"];
                if ([after isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    nextPageRequest = [[OLFacebookAlbumRequest alloc] init];
                    nextPageRequest.after = after;
                }
            }
        }

        handler(albums, nil, nextPageRequest);
    }];
}
else {
    NSString *message = @"No Facebook user authentication found.";
    handler(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:kOLErrorDomainFacebookImagePicker code:kOLErrorCodeFacebookImagePickerNoOpenSession userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message}], nil);
}
}




//Code for fetching albums...
- (void)loadNextAlbumPage {
self.inProgressRequest = self.albumRequestForNextPage;
self.albumRequestForNextPage = nil;
[self.inProgressRequest getAlbums:^(NSArray/*<OLFacebookAlbum>*/ *albums, NSError *error, OLFacebookAlbumRequest *nextPageRequest) {
    self.inProgressRequest = nil;
    self.loadingIndicator.hidden = YES;
    self.albumRequestForNextPage = nextPageRequest;

    if (error) {
        if (self.parentViewController.isBeingPresented) {
            self.loadingIndicator.hidden = NO;
            self.getAlbumError = error; // delay notification so that delegate can dismiss view controller safely if desired.
        } else {
            [self.delegate albumViewController:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
        return;
    }

    NSMutableArray *paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < albums.count; ++i) {
        [paths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.albums.count + i inSection:0]];
    }

    [self.albums addObjectsFromArray:albums];
    if (self.albums.count == albums.count) {
        // first insert request
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    if (nextPageRequest) {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.loadingFooter;
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
    }

}];
}

 //And when they signed up:

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,first_name,photos,picture.width(400).height(400)"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) { //etc etc the method continues.
```

Comment: Have you requested the permission for accessing photos (user_photos)? The other problem is FB has to first review your asking for this permission before your app can use it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_photos

Comment: As in when they signed up:  [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,first_name,photos,picture.width(400).height(400)"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) { //etc etc the method continues as I create the user on my server using these downloaded Facebook attributes...

Comment: I am sort of a little confused on whether "user_photos" is different from asking permission to see "photos" when the user signs up, if someone could shed light on this that would be on fleek.

Comment: No, a different access token is generated each time you request different permissions. My bet is your access token doesn't have permissions attached to it to access user photos. How did you request the access token?

Comment: You have to explicitly request the user_photos permission before accessing photos.

Comment: Okay, so I'll leave that parameter out of the original signup flow, and then request it here. So are you saying every time it boots up the app it creates a new access token...? And I'd have to init a new permissions request to the user to get like the name, first_name, etc?

Comment: Could you add a snapshot of code of somewhere you are doing something like this? It is a rather simple fix, you don't have to exclude requesting photos. :) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#permissions

Comment: FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",  @"user_photos"];
    CGRect f = loginButton.frame;
    f.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width - f.size.width) / 2;
    f.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height - f.size.height) / 2;
    loginButton.frame = f;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];

Comment: Something like that is what I should add, right? Just a little button to ask permission...I can get started with adding that to my flow right away....

Comment: That's right. If you don't have this, you'll need it.

Comment: Let me ask another question, however. How come on Tinder I don't have to give them permission every time I want to choose an image from facebook? Is it because you only need to authorize user_photos once??

Comment: That's right :) You only need to request permissions once, unless the user specifically revokes it from facebook.

Comment: Once sorted, let me know and I can add a summary answer below. :)

Comment: Will do, need to figure out my UI for where exactly I want to put the button, since it's sort of involved in a Tableview. Should have it completed within 48 hours, taking a break now.

Comment: Good good, no problem. Comment/tag me if you have any other issues. I can't help with Objective-C but I have done plenty of work with the fb graph api.

Comment: I got it running perfectly, go ahead and write an answer whenever and I'll mark it right. All I had to do was execute a permissions request as we discussed.

Comment: That's great! Will do in a few hours :)

Comment: One weird thing I'm running into is {access token hasgranted"user_photos"} is returning false, but when I conduct FBLogin, it says "you have already authorized..." and then after you press ok it shows al the photos. So why does the current access token not seem to think that it has authorized, but then when I call FBLogin it's all good?

Comment: so weirdly, I have to refresh the acces token before checking permissions. Then I get my photos.

Comment: It seems like it would make sense to hand me an access token with current permissions when the app boots up, right...?

Comment: Not when it boots up - once you request and are granted permission you'll get a specific token. Persist that and use that each time.

Comment: So why do I have to refresh it?

Comment: Also can you define persist. I'm not saving it on a file or on a private server of course...

Comment: Sorry was AFK. Persist it on the phone for that user. Here's the process I would use. Download app -> sign in -> request permission and get token -> save token on the phone to reuse -> use that token for every subsequent call to fb. If you reopen the app, and you have a saved/valid token, use that, otherwise send them to the login screen.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes i did solve this it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB authentication will give you a unique `access_token` for a particular set of permissions. To access user photos, you need to request the `user_photos` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_photos). Use the `FBSDKLoginButton` to request permissions.

```
loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_photos"];
```

Once you have an access token with the required permissions, persist that locally (on the device) to reuse in future. If the access code is still valid, you won't need to request it again. If it becomes invalid (in case the user explicitly revoked permissions to your app), send them back to the login screen.